# 'belongs_to' association with form_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This question is about the new **form_with** helper in Rails. The particular case is when the form is for a model that **belongs_to** another. Here's some code.

Routes.rb

```
resources :contents do
  resources :translations
end
```

Migration

```
class CreateTranslations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :translations do |t|
      t.text :translation
      t.string :to_lang
      t.references :content, foreign_key: true, dependent: :delete
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Form

```
<%= form_with(model: @translation, url: [@content, @translation], local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if translation.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(translation.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this translation from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% translation.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label "Target Language", class: "label" %>
    <div class="select"> 
      <%= form.select(:to_lang, options_for_select([["English", "en"], ["French", "fr"], ["Spanish", "es"]])) %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label "Original Content" %>
    <%= form.label translation.content.text %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Translation_controller.rb

```
def new
   @content = Content.find(params[:content_id])
   @translation = @content.translations.new
end

def create
  @content = Content.find(params[:content_id])
  @translation = @content.translations.build(translation_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @translation.save
      format.html { redirect_to contents_path, notice: 'Translation was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @translation }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @translation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

## Questions

This code seems to work but I think I can improve it. When I look at params in the create action I see this:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dFdTw+d85qA2BsLb0OW4TcaVfkMIaNEYgXcPvE8ff5ANprfoL58clGlx5kSC5zzoSOM0nSf9kaNvH8ebpUj5JQ==", "translation"=>{"to_lang"=>"en"}, "commit"=>"Create Translation", "controller"=>"translations", "action"=>"create", "content_id"=>"1"} permitted: false>
```

1. As you can see the content_id parameter is not under the translation => hash parameter which then makes my strong params not find it. Is there a better way?

Secondly this leads me to code the create action like this:

```
@content = Content.find(params[:content_id])
@translation = @content.translations.build(translation_params)
```

2. which doesn't seem right because again I am bypassing strong params. I know this is purely an aesthetic issue and I don't think harms security or whatever. Is there a better way?

Also my form_with looks like this:

```
<%= form_with(model: @translation, url: [@content, @translation], local: true) do |form| %>
```

3. Which I got to mostly by googling and trial-and-error. Is that the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `content_id` is not in the translation hash by Rails design.   however, you could do the following to clean things up a bit

```
class TranslationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_content, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @translation = @content.translations.new
  end

  def create
    @translation = @content.translations.build(translation_params)
    ...
  end

  private

  def set_content
    # use params.require to use strong params
    @content = Content.find(params.require(:content_id))
  end
end
```

if you use `@content` in other actions, just adjust the `before_action` filter accordingly

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. How do we know that this is the intended design? What's the reasoning as far as you know?

Comment: hmm, if you read the Rails Routing, Outside in, any reference variables in the path show it as a top level params element. 
 there's at least 5 examples included in the docs, including: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions  - I'm not sure the reasoning, but its consistent and assumes no relationship in the routing path